# static arrays are not the same [java]

Tags: java, arrays, static

I'm trying to create a Java program that generates an amount of seats taken in an airplane. So far, I have been able to do this, but my problem is every time I run the client the numbers generated are different. I need them to be the same every time...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anybody help me?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Airplane {
    public static Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    public static int[] oSeatLeft = new int[10];
    public static int[] mSeatLeft = new int[10];
    public static int[] wSeatLeft = new int[10];
    public static int oSeat = 0;
    public static int mSeat = 0;
    public static int wSeat = 0;
    public static final int sCheck = 0;

    public void genWSeats() {

        int randSeatFill = 0;
        if (wSeat == 0) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < wSeatLeft.length; counter++) {
                randSeatFill = randomNumbers.nextInt(2);
                if (randSeatFill == 1) {
                    wSeatLeft[counter] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (wSeat == 0) {
                wSeat++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] getWSeats() {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(wSeatLeft));
        return wSeatLeft;
    }
}
```

The purpose of static int **wSeat** is supposed to be a checker. If **wSeat** is greater than zero, then it should not randomly generate numbers for the array. Not sure exactly what is going wrong here....

Comment: I'm creating random data and its coming out randomly. What sort of magic is this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Random` constructor with *seed*

```
public static Random randomNumbers = new Random(42);
```

This way always the same sequence of random numbers is generated.
42 is only an example, you can use any value you want.

Comment: okay great, seems to work so far. I just deleted the checker if statement, and the answers stay the same.... I assume this is okay...

Comment: Thanks! That helps a wicked lot! So my problem now is.... when I create multiple objects that are an extension of this class, the random numbers in each class are still the same.... is there a way to only initialize one variable, but have it generate different numbers for each class?

Comment: @Brian Murphy: I think this could be a little tricky. Each class would need its own static `Random`-instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a seed on initialization with [`Random(long seed)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29).  This will guarantee that the sequence of numbers generated is always the same (since it's a pseudo-random number generator).

Answer (score 1):

Pass Seed in constructor of `Random` it will generate the same number every time